# How do I add together these checked inputs prices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am using this code I need to add together any inputs that are checked price values. They price values are dynamically generated. but for the purpose of being on here they have a value. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```js
var $variantTitle = $('.variant_title');
var $variantPrice = $('.variant_price');

$('#products :checkbox').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var title = $row.find('.title').text();
    var price = $row.find('.price').text();
    $variantTitle.text(title);
    $variantPrice.text(price);
  } else {
    $variantTitle.empty();
    $variantPrice.empty();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="products">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="variant_title"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="updates[31435395282]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / S - <span class="price">$0.01</span></td>
      <td class="title hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / S - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="updates[31435395346]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / M - <span class="price">$0.01</span></td>
      <td class="title hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / M - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="updates[31435395410]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / L - <span class="price">$0.01</span></td>
      <td class="title hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / L - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="variant_price"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example, on each click, call a `.each` function to loop through all checkbox and if the checkbox is checked add it to the total price, at the end output total price.

Here

```
+($(this).parent().next('td').find('.price').text().replace(/\$/g, ''));
```

Find the checked price use `$(this).parent().next('td').find('.price')`
Then `.text().replace(/\$/g, ''));` to find the price and replace the `$`
`+` will force the variable to become number, otherwise you are just concating string like 0.010.01 instead of 0.02.

```js
var $variantTitle = $('.variant_title');
var $variantPrice = $('.variant_price');

$('#products :checkbox').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var title = $row.find('.title').text();
    var price = $row.find('.price').text();
    $variantTitle.text(title);
    $variantPrice.text(price);
  } else {
    $variantTitle.empty();
    $variantPrice.empty();
  }
  //handling total price
  var total = 0;
  $('#products :checkbox').each(function(){
    if(this.checked){
      total += +($(this).parent().next('td').find('.price').text().replace(/\$/g, ''));
    }
  })
  //output your total price
  $('#total_price').text(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="products">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="variant_title"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="updates[31435395282]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / S - <span class="price">$0.01</span></td>
      <td class="title hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / S - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="updates[31435395346]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / M - <span class="price">$0.01</span></td>
      <td class="title hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / M - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="updates[31435395410]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / L - <span class="price">$0.01</span></td>
      <td class="title hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / L - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="variant_price"></div>

<div>Total Price: $<span id="total_price">0</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help!

Comment: @JCQ50 glad to help